# How to read Hive Table with Spark-Sql efficiently

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hive, apache-spark-sql

I have a table with 20GB data in hive, I am reading the table using spark with hive context and I am able to see the data and schema as expected.

However it is taking around 40 mins to read the data, is there any alternative to read the data from hive table efficiently.

**Hive Table** Sample_Table - 20 GB, No partitions, using ORC Snappy Compression. (data exploded to 120 GB while reading from spark)

**spark** = `SparkSession.builder().enableHiveSupport()getOrCreate()`

```
val spark_table = spark.sql(select * from Sample_Table)
```

**Environment Details -** 
Not using any cloud

Nodes - Around 850, total memory - 160 TB, 80 V cores per node, upto 300GB memory per node, 22 Disks per node

**Spark-Submit command** -

```
/mapr/spark/bin/spark-submit \
--verbose
--num-executors=30 \
--conf spark.locality.wait=60s \
--conf spark.network.timeout=14080s \
--driver-memory=20G \
--executor-memory=15G \
--conf spark.blacklist.enabled=true \
--conf spark.shuffle.service.enabled=true \
--master yarn \
--name=Sample_xxx \
--conf spark.default.parallelism=25 \
--conf spark.task.cpus=3 \
--conf spark.broadcast.compress=true \
--conf spark.io.compression.codec=lz4 \
--conf spark.shuffle.compress=true \
--conf "spark.executor.cores=3" \
--conf spark.shuffle.spill.compress=true \
--conf spark.rdd.compress=true \
--conf spark.sql.shuffle.partitions=1000 \
--conf spark.yarn.executor.memoryOverhead=3G \
--conf spark.sql.tungsten.enabled=true \
--queue sample1XX \
--class XXX yy.jar
```

I am reading multiple tables and performing multiple transformations, that's the reason I have below configurations in spark submit command

Answer (score 0):

20GB should not take very long, though if it decompresses to 120GB that is a more substantial workload; please describe what kind of hardware you are using.

I guess from the path to `spark-submit` that you are using the MapR distribution of Hadoop. Does this include a user interface giving additional insight into performance? Look particularly for memory usage / garbage collection.

Are there any other jobs running on your cluster that might be taking resources?

Is the 40 minutes merely to load the data, or does this include your processing (bear in mind that Spark loads data lazily, so timings can sometimes be misleading)?

The main thing I notice is that `spark.yarn.executor.memory` is not a valid spark setting, so your executors may be short of memory.

Use the `--executor-memory` setting instead.

Also add the `--verbose` flag and study the output when you run your job, to ensure that the settings are correct and are being parsed in the way you expect.

Also check the executor logs to ensure that there are no errors, particularly due to running out of memory.

*Minor observations:*

You are setting `spark.shuffle.spill.compress` twice (harmless but unnecessary)

You are setting both `--num-executors` and `spark.dynamicAllocation.enabled=true`, which are contradictory, and normally result in a warning message saying that dynamic allocation will be disabled.

Comment: (updated the spark submit command) I have applied the changes, now I can see all the configurations were being passed as expected,and no other jobs were running in my queue, still time taken to read the table is around 30-40 mins!

Comment: Can you please update your question with some details on what hardware you are running on? i.e. is this server-class hardware? How many physical nodes (or VMs), with how much memory and how many cores, and how many disks per node (or what type of VMs if you are running in cloud).

Comment: OK, that looks fine. I'd recommend looking at the Spark UI and see if anything looks odd for your job in terms of task duration, GC, task distribution/skew, long delays or dead executors on the timeline, etc

Comment: I don't see anything significant in either executor logs or spark UI, I am not sure if I can use any parameter to read ORC snappy compressed tables efficiently from hive to be included in spark-submit command. Thanks!